# Javascript not running in a synchronous fashion

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have two functions that are inserting data into the DB. Function updateScratcherGameData inserts the game name and id into the game table. Then calls the second function, updateScratcherRowData, which inserts the raw data I scraped into another table scratcher_data. Function updateScratcherRowData needs to assign a foreign key that it gets from the game table. When I run the functions separately, they work as intended. But when I run them together, I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'game_id')

It appears updateScratcherRowData is running before updateScratcherGameData inserts the game_id. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
function updateScratcherGameData(cleanData){
  
  // Insert into database games that do not exist yet
  uniqueGameData.map(e=>{
    const insertGameData = `INSERT INTO game (name,scratcher_lotto_id,gametype_id,active) VALUES ('${e["name"]}',${e["scratcher_id"]},1,1);`;

    connection.query(`SELECT name FROM game WHERE name='${e["name"]}';`, (err,rows)=>{  
      if (err){
        throw err;
      }
        if(rows.length===0){
        connection.query(insertGameData)
        console.log('insertion into game table done!');   
        }     
      }
    )})
    updateScratcherRowData(cleanData)

}
```

```
function updateScratcherRowData(cleanData){

  cleanData.map(e=>{
    connection.query(`SELECT game_id FROM game WHERE name='${e["name"]}' AND scratcher_lotto_id='${e["scratcher_id"]}';`, (err,rows)=>{  
      const insertScratcherData = `INSERT INTO scratcher_data (scrape_date,game_id,prize,odds,remaining_prize,total_prize) VALUES ((TIMESTAMP(NOW())),${rows[0]["game_id"]},${e["prize"]},${e["odds"]},${e["tickets_left"]},${e["tickets_remaining"]});`

      if (err){
        console.log('problem updating scratcher row data');
        throw err;
      }
        connection.query(insertScratcherData)
      }
    )})
  }
```

I tried running the functions separately and they work. Together, they do not. I tried changing where I call the updateScratcherRowData function and still get the same error

Comment: `connection.query` is asynchronous ... so, you'd be executing `updateScratcherRowData` before the queries in `uniqueGameData.map` run

Comment: okay, so i should make them aync/await then do a Promise.all?

Comment: you're not using promises, so async/await won't help

Comment: @doedoe yes, use promises to ensure synchronous flow of database operations.

Comment: redid all the functions with async/await and added them to Promise.all, same error occurred. I added a `setTimeout()` for the `updateScratcherRowData`, and this resolved the issue. However, I know this isn't optimal...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add another error handling after `insertGameData` and call the 2nd function there. Something like this :

```
function updateScratcherGameData(cleanData){
  
  // Insert into database games that do not exist yet
  uniqueGameData.map(e=>{
    const insertGameData = `INSERT INTO game (name,scratcher_lotto_id,gametype_id,active) VALUES ('${e["name"]}',${e["scratcher_id"]},1,1);`;

    connection.query(`SELECT name FROM game WHERE name='${e["name"]}';`, (err,rows)=>{  
      if (err){
        throw err;
      }
        if(rows.length===0){
        connection.query(insertGameData,  (err,rows)=>{  
         if (err){
           throw err;
         }
           console.log('insertion into game table done!');
           console.log('now trying to update scratcher row data');  
           updateScratcherRowData(cleanData)  
         })
        }     
      }
    )})
}
```